# Android Posting on Facebook Page as an Admin/Facebook Page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am integrating facebook sdk. I want to post on facebook page directly from my application. It should be posted as an Admin or as a Page of the page, but unfortunately it is posting as a user (In Visitor Posts Section) on the page. You can see in screenshot. P.S I have Admin role at this page. Here is my code.

```
                       LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            shareFacebook();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                        }
                    });
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(ShareScreen.this, Arrays.asList("manage_pages,publish_pages"));
```

Here is my graph API post request **shareFacebook();** function.

```
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(accessToken, pageID+"/videos"
            , null, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            progress.dismiss();
            if(response.getError()==null)
                Toast.makeText(ShareScreen.this, "Shared on facebook page.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(ShareScreen.this, "Error while sharing on facebook page.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    Bundle params = request.getParameters();
   params.putString("description", "Lorum ipsum..");
        request.setParameters(params);
        request.executeAsync();
```

You can see I am getting "manage_pages,publish_pages" permissions as well.
Thanks in Advance for your comments and help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to resolve my issue. I have read [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#page-access-tokens) , Problem was that I was publishing new post using my user account's access token instead of page's access token. So I have made "me/accounts" Graph Api call using my user account's access token. So All I was able to get all pages with their relevant access tokens. Now I can post at facebook page as **Page**.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar with my application. I am not able to find any documentation on how to use the page access token in Android Graph API. I have generated a never expiring token, but I am not sure where to pass it. Can you please help?

Comment: @G3M Please login user with the access of pages that user manages. When user done with the login than get all pages associated with the users account. Than loop through the list and get access token for pages.